# Getting problems when trying to setup Jetpack Compose Found interface rPluginContext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

So, I'm trying to let jetpack compose run with a simple example, I have already updated my kotlin plugin to 1.4.0 and also updated all my build gradle with the jetpack compose documentation, but I got this error when compiling

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.extensions.IrPluginContext, but
> class was expected    at
> androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:41)

I have also downloaded the canary version of Android studio

### build.gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0-rc"
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
      url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
      url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/"
    }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jetpackcompose"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  buildFeatures {
    // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
    compose true
  }

  // Set both the Java and Kotlin compilers to target Java 8.

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }

    composeOptions {
      kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
      kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev13"
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'


    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-core:0.1.0-dev13'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev13'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev13'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev13'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
  }


tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies", "-Xskip-prerelease-check"]
  }
}
```

But I cant compile the app, I'm trying to run the basic example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent{
        sayHello()
    }
  }

  @Preview
  @Composable
  fun sayHello(){
    Text("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Does anyone knows why this error is thrown ?

Comment: Your Kotlin version is unusual, and `kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version` is wrong. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/26/upgrading-dev15-jetpack-compose.html) for how to set up a `dev15` project. Or, wait a month or two, and documentation may improve once we start getting alpha releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update Compose version to `0.1.0-dev16`. Looks like `0.1.0-dev13` isn't compatible with Kotlin `1.4-rc`

Answer (score 4):

Using Kotlin version 1.4.10 instead of 1.4.20 solved my problem.